# How come one user can delete another user's 755 files?

Tags: linux, security, file-permissions

I have a backup upload script that scp’s files to another server using the user `upload`. Another script on the target server then chown’s these to another user and sets the file mode to `755`.

If I then SSH into the target server using the `upload` user, I’m able to delete the chowned files. Shouldnt they be read only?

Here is what a file looks like on the target server, and the user `upload` is able to delete it.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 maciekish maciekish 650M Nov  1 01:07 2014-11-01-data.tar.bz2
```

The user `upload` was just added using `useradd` and is not a part of the `maciekish` group.

When trying to delete the file as `upload` via ssh I get the question whether I want to delete “write protected regular file” and I’m able to say `Y` and delete it.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Why can `rm` remove read-only files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48579/80216)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The files *are* read-only; however, deleting a file doesn't modify it but only the parent directory (it basically removes the file from directory listing) – and it sounds like you have full write permissions to the directory.

You can set the `sticky` bit—aka “restricted deletion” flag—which will prevent anyone except the owner from renaming or deleting files in that directory (like in `/tmp`). To do this, run `chmod o+t *directory*` as the owner of the directory.

Answer (score 12):

In a typical Unix filesystem, any file can be identified by an arbitrary number of directory entries, each of which holds a "hard link".

From an implementation standpoint there is a difference between deleting the last directory entry (hard link) for a file and simply deleting one reference out of of many. However, from a semantic standpoint there is no difference.

If multiple hard links exist to a file, writing to the file using any of them alters the file seen by all of them.  Using `rm` on a link, however, merely causes the file to not be accessible via that link. Other links to the file continue to see the exact same file.

Comment: Commonly known as hard links.

Comment: @Bob: I know the term "hard link" is used to describe references that are created to an already-existing file; in cases where a file has never had more than one reference to it, is that lone reference still called a "hard link"?

Comment: There is no difference between the links. Create file A, create hard link B, delete file A. Is B now a file or a hard link? For understanding how it works, it's better to see it as N hard links and not as 1 file and (N-1) hard links. There's also the links that exist when a file is opened.

Comment: @gnasher729: I agree that in cases where multiple links exist or have existed to a file, it makes sense to refer to all of them as "hard links" if there's no semantic difference between them.  On the other hand, I would think that from both a semantic and performance standpoint there could be advantages to distinguishing between a directory entry that has always been the only reference to a file, versus one to which other hard links may have been created.  In any case, I didn't know whether it would be correct to refer say of the directory entries, "each of which is called a 'hard link'".

Comment: @supercat it's not incredibly common, but it is correct. Consider the `st_nlink` ("number of hard links") field in `struct stat`. Put simply, directories hold hard links to files.

Comment: @hobbs: Do you like my edit?